# How to avoid changing my bash command use in all my scipts

Tags: bash

So i have a bash command that has the following options 
-v -o  -T  -S -I -e -t 
-t has been changed to -x and -T and -e are no longer availabe.
How can i avoid changing all scripts that use this command with these options that are no longer available or have changed?

Comment: `ABashCmd()(ABashCmdCompatWrapper "$@"); export -f ABashCmd; MyScript` ? But better just to fix the scripts

Comment: im sorry but i didn't get your answer

Comment: @AmineAbouhodaifa, it looks like jhnc is asking you to put function wrapper around your  changed command ( which they are calling ABashCmd ).  So it's a similar answer, I just used a bash program (and the PATH) and showed you a way ( a bad way ) to modify the parameters. With jhnc's approach, you'll need to define `ABashCmdCompatWrapper` to modify the parameters as you require and then call the version of `ABashCmd` that just changed on youo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a wrapper for your bash command and put it in the PATH before the other executable that is changing.

For instance:

Imaging that the changing bash command is in the /c directory and this is your PATH:

```
PATH=/a:/b:/c
```

One approach is to put the wrapper with the same name in the /a (or /b) directory - that is, in the PATH before /c.   So, let's say your old script is called `old` and it's in the /c directory.  You can create an `old` script in the `/a` directory, and have it call the other script:

```
COMMAND="/c/old $( sed -e "s:-x::g" -e "s:-T::g"  <<< "$@" )"
$COMMAND
```

So the idea is to manipulate the command arguments before calling the /c/old script.  This will need a bit of adjusting if the parameters are more complicated (like they can take a value).  There is also likely a quoting issue, it is unlikely that quotes will survive this approach.

If you need to get more complicated, you may consider getopts as a way of parsing the parameters better in the /a/old script.

To be honest, I'm not so happy with this answer - it will not work in a general case.  But you asked :) ...